# C++ String Property Call to C#

Tags: c#, c++

I support an old VS 2010 C++ Video Application.  This application calls Video Integrators that are written in C# 2015 (and older versions as well).  We have run into a unique issue that I have pinpointed to being the transfer of a camera list from the Integrator to the Video App, where the string of data is truncated at exactly 5087 characters.  (resulting in only 88 of the 134 cameras being loaded into the Video Application)  I am not strong at C++ at all, so I'm not entirely certain what other options I have for data objects and definition.  I totally presume the issue is on the C++ side, because I can see the complete outgoing list of cameras in the C# Integrator code. (but maybe I'm mistaken)

> //Video Application code  (c++ 2010)
>
> deviceLibrary.h file

```
//get setting extended
typedef TCHAR* (*DI_GETSETTINGEX)(HWND hParentWnd, int nParameter,LPARAM lParam);
#define DI_GETSETTINGEX_ENTRY "GetSettingEx"

class CDeviceLibrary : public CCameraWindow
{
public:

DI_GETSETTINGEX m_pGetSettingEx;
};
```

> deviceLibrary.cpp

```
CDeviceLibrary::CDeviceLibrary(int nId,LPCTSTR pszName,LPCTSTR pszView,HINSTANCE hLib,HWND hWnd,LPCTSTR pszLibrary,LPCTSTR pszPropertiesString)
{
    m_pGetSettingEx = (DI_GETSETTINGEX)GetProcAddress(m_hLib,DI_GETSETTINGEX_ENTRY);
}

CString CDeviceLibrary::GetSetting(int nSetting,LPARAM lParam)
{
    if(m_pGetSettingEx)
        return m_pGetSettingEx(AfxGetMainWnd()->m_hWnd,nSetting,lParam);
    else if(m_pGetSetting)
        return m_pGetSetting(nSetting,lParam);
    return _T("");
}
```

> ConfigureServers.cpp

```
void CConfigurationServers::LoadCameras()
{
//RIGHT HERE! THE VALUE OF strCameras only contains 5087 characters in it, when it is supposed to contain over 7000
    CString strCameras = GetSetting(ParameterGetCameraList,(LPARAM)(LPCTSTR)strParameters);
}
```

> Video Integrator Code Base (C# 2010, .NET 4.0)

```
public virtual String GetLibrarySetting(int Parameter,int lParam)
{
    return GetCameraList(Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi((IntPtr)lParam)); 
}

        virtual public String GetCameraList()
        {
            String CameraList = "";
            try
            {
                if(!Connected)
                    Connect();
                if(DeviceList.Count > 0)
                {
                    List<BaseCamera>.Enumerator Cameras = DeviceList.GetEnumerator();
                    while(Cameras.MoveNext())
                    {
                        BaseCamera Camera = Cameras.Current;
                        int FeatureFlags = (int)CameraFlags.FLAG_PTZ_SUPPORT | (Camera.PTZ?(int)CameraFlags.FLAG_PTZ:0) |
                        (int)CameraFlags.FLAG_AUDIO_SUPPORT | (Camera.AudioIn?(int)CameraFlags.FLAG_AUDIO:0) |
                        (int)CameraFlags.FLAG_MIKE_SUPPORT | 
                        (Camera.RecordNotSupported ? (int)CameraFlags.FLAG_NO_RECORD_SUPPORT | (int)CameraFlags.FLAG_NO_RECORD : 0);
                    CameraList += String.Format("{0};{1};{2}\n", Camera.Title.Length > 0 ? Camera.Title : Camera.Name, Camera.CameraId, FeatureFlags);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                LogException(e.Message);
            }
            return CameraList;
        }
```

I am not the original creator of either of these applications.  If you ask me a "why did you do...." question, I have no idea what the answer is.  If any of you know of a solution that can seamlessly replace this solution, and retrieve me the full string I am looking for, wonderful.  If you see the reason why I only a subset of the original list of characters is being received into the Video App, please let me know why.  Thanks!

NOTE:  I have stripped out hundreds of lines of code in this post.  The code base is massive.

> Sample text being passed, and how it is being truncated at the C++ property:

C001-P100--1-SeeTec (Peliquin);4611967493405284623;2293760
C001-P100--SeeTec (Peliquin);4611967493405284639;2293760
C002-P100--1-SeeTec (Peliquin);4611967493405284632;2293760
C002-P100--SeeTec (Peliquin);4611967493405284646;2293760
C003-P100--1-SeeTec (Peliquin);4611967493405284660;2293760
C003-P100--SeeTec (Peli"

Comment: [MCVE] that reproduces thr problem?

Comment: Possibly throwing an exception (in `GetCameraList`) processing the 89th camera?

Comment: `CString` can hold more than that. I'd check the documentation of the API you are using.

Comment: I couldn't possibly include all the code needed to recreate the exact issue.   The question at hand, is I'm wondering if somewhere in the setup of the properties and the retrieval of the Camera List, would the way it is coded, possibly be causing this oddity?

Comment: The C++ property to retrieve the cameras, only ends up with the first 5087 characters, which ends in the middle of a Camera Title.  strCameraList is a '/n' delimited list of cameras, that the C++ code splits and processes.  The cameras that make it there, process fine.

Comment: I've never used: Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi()   Are there limitations to it?

Are there limitations to using LPCTSTR?

Comment: GetCameraList ends with all cameras properly added on the C# side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arg... as it turns out, C++ cannot (at least in our app) directly call a C# application.  It needs an app in the middle to do some sort of conversion between the two languages.  I tracked down a tiny c++ application in our system that is referenced by the program that makes the two languages talk to each other, which had the following code in it:

```
wchar_t* ConvertToCharW(String^ Input)
{
    static wchar_t ch[5001]=L""; //TODO: make dynamic so no String^ length limit
    try
    {
        ch[0] = ch[5000] = '\0';
    // Pin memory so GC can't move it while native function is called
        pin_ptr<const wchar_t> wch = PtrToStringChars(Input);
        wcscpy_s(ch,5000,wch);
    }
    catch(...)
    {
    }
    return ch;
}
```

And there is my 5000 character limit.  Since I have no idea how to make it dynamic in C++, I changed it to 20000.